# How to decode base64 using C?

Tags: c, base64

I am trying to create a C web client for a web API. The API sends a file divided by chunks, base64 encoded, as a JSON string. I was able to receive data and extract the payload from JSON, but I cannot decode base64 encoded chunk using C. For this purpose I use such library: https://web.mit.edu/freebsd/head/contrib/wpa/src/utils/base64.c
If I try to work with test strings it works fine:

```
size_t out_len = 0;
unsigned char *test = "U29tZVRlc3RUZXh0";
unsigned char *res = base64_decode(test, strlen(test), &out_len);
printf("%s", res); //prints "SomeTestText"
```

But when decoding a chunk, for example, one of them you can see here: https://mega.nz/file/K8gDWJiI#oZagaBN2hWFdpUKOv-glE-ySh4JVvnTdRNfgOGY9jzM
It returns NULL or only several first symbols. What am I doing wrong? The chunks are fragments of a ZIP archive binary. If I use, for example, Golang for the same purpose, it works as expected... How can I decode my chunks?

Comment: Probably because these are not strings but some arbitrary binary data, which can't be printed as string (that is, has zero bytes here and there....)

Comment: `ZIP archive binary` What would you expect if you would print a zip archive binary?

Comment: I expect to receive a sequence of bytes, like this
PKWVЏOюЎ(•(8)package1.aupіЈeP\_–> Xраn оо. NЅ!@pw hpВїїч Є;ЅЭЅtжѕпЋ÷ї[[µыељUѕфЬџѕй~Їѕ93чj(#љ}чжњ
ETC...

Comment: And you did receive a sequence of bytes. You just chose to look at them in a way that doesn't make sense for that kind of data. Try printing `out_len`, or look at what `res` points to in a debugger.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first bytes in the base64 encoded PK Zip archive (named after its author [Phil Katz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phil_Katz)) you linked to are:

```
0 0x50 P
1 0x4b K
2 0x03
3 0x04
4 0x14
5 0x00
```

The four first are `\x50\x4b\x03\x04` which is PK Zips "magic" number.

The next two contains the version number. Notice how the sixth byte is `0x00`? This is where `printf` will stop printing since it will interpret that as a string terminator, which is why you will only see `PK` written to the console. The other three characters are most likely invisible.

Also note that the archive is not complete, so not even if you write it to a file ...

```c
int main(void) {
    size_t out_len = 0;
    unsigned char *res = base64_decode(test, strlen(test), &out_len);
    FILE* fp = fopen("out.zip", "wb");
    if(fp) {
        fwrite(res, out_len, 1, fp);
        fclose(fp);
    }
}
```

... will you be able to `unzip` it afterwards. The base64 decoding part does the correct thing though.

Answer (score 2):

A ZIP archive contains binary data. You can decode binary contents with `base64_decode()`, but you cannot print binary data directly with `printf`.  The decoded chunk is in the array returned by the function and has a length of `out_len` bytes.